# What are all the difference between these two Javascript functions?

Tags: javascript, callback

1:

```
var sum = function (a, b){ return a+b; }
```

2:

```
var sum = function (a, b, callback ){ console.log(a+b); callback; }
```

I am trying to understand callback functions but I am not what is the key differences here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One *returns* the result of adding (or concatenating) `a` and `b`.

The other *logs* that to the console instead of returning anything.

The `callback` variable isn't used. It is just mentioned, but that does nothing. It might as well not be there.

Answer (score 0):

These two functions are completely different. If you are looking into callback functions then second line would probably be something like:

```
var sum = function (a, b, callback) { return callback(a+b); }
```

where then callback could be:

```
var callback = function(a, b) { return a + b; }
```

So in short, callback is function which you pass into another function as parameter and then invoke it within the body of that function. Standard usage is in async scenarios where we want to invoke callback e.g. once we receive data from our server.